# Combining Google & Facebook OAuth 2.0

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

A person has a gmail account registered with EXAMPLE@GMAIL.COM.

The person also has a facebook account registered with email address EXAMPLE@GMAIL.COM.

MyWebsite.com offers sign-up with Google and sign-up with Facebook.

The person signs up for MyWebsite.com using **Google** OAuth 2.0.

The person then logs in to MyWebsite.com using **Facebook** OAuth 2.0.

Are there any security issues with Combining Google & Facebook OAuth 2.0 in this manor i.e. the person only has one account with MyWebsite.com but can use both Google & Facebook OAuth 2.0 interchangeably to login to MyWebsite.com independent of what method they used to register on MyWebsite.com?

Comment: Facebook only returns verified email addresses, I’m guessing with Google it is the same. So as long as you request the email from their APIs using a server-side call, there should not be a problem. (You obviously don’t want to make the API call on the client side, and then sent the resulting user data to your backend from there - because that could easily be faked by the user.)

Comment: @CBroe  Yes Facebook only returns verified email addresses in my experience, for Google I do not think it is physically possible to have an unverified gmail address in my above scenario. Yes API calls always more secure from server side rather than client but my question relates specifically to security risks in combining Google & Facebook OAuth 2.0 in the above scenario